# Upgrading Angular from 9 to 10 Error: Package '-e' is not a dependency

Tags: angular, angular9, angular10

has anybody here bumped into the following issue when updating an angular app from 9 to 10.

```
"Package '-e' is not a dependency."
```

That happens when running `ng update @angular/core@10 @angular/cli@10`

Did some googling but there's not a single result out there that matches my issue (that's gotta be a first)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you aren't using '-force'.  Instead, use the correct '--force' parameter.

Comment: This was the solution for me, thank you! :DOH:

Answer (score 2):

After taking backup:

try to update CLI first

```
npm i @angular/cli@10
```

then core

```
ng update @angular/core@10
```

or

```
ng update @angular/core@10 --force
```